# When I change url in a middleware, it does not jump to next middleware even that middleware match pattern path

Tags: node.js, express

When i rewrite url in a middleware, express will go to next first middleware, but no go to next middleware even that middleware match pattern path. Example code below. When I browse http://localhost:3000, the console log message

> middleware1
>
> middleware2

so that it not jump to middleware3

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/',function (req, res, next) {
 // i want to rewrite url to http://localhost:3000/next but not redirect page
 req.url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl + 'nxt' 
 console.log('middleware1');
 next()
})

app.use('/nxt',function (req, res, next) {
 console.log('middleware2');
 next()
})

app.use('/nxt',function (req, res, next) {
 console.log('middleware3');
 next()
})

app.listen(3000);
```

But when I browse url http://localhost:3000/nxt, the console log message

> middleware2
>
> middleware3

so that it jump to middleware3

Or if I change "app.use" by "app.get" or "app.all", it still jump to middleware3 when I browse url http://localhost:3000

Please explain for me why? is that a bug? Thanks!

Comment: You can not use the same `url` multiple times.

Comment: but when I change code to

    `app.use('/next',function (req, res, next) {
 console.log('middleware2');
 next()
    }, function (req, res, next) {
 console.log('middleware3');
 next()
    })`

it still not jump to middleware3

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: I want to change url but not redirect user to that page, only change the page content

Comment: So you want when you enter `http://localhost:3000` then only `middleware 1` prints.

Comment: No, I want 3 middleware print. If I use `app.get('/next',function (req, res, next) {
 console.log('middleware2');
 next()
})` and `app.get('/next',function (req, res, next) {
 console.log('middleware3');
 next()
})` all 3 middleware print. But I dont know why that?

Comment: @PhạmNgọcChuyển is there anything you're not showing in the example? Because I tested your example and all the middleware (1,2,3) were executed for `http://localhost:3000`... (node v10.11.0, express v4.16.3)

Comment: oh if I modify app.get('/next' by app.get('/nxt', it works not correctly. This is my video test https://drive.google.com/open?id=14GJhTWsX6wWn560cervdSFv_bW83ZsX1

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do as -

```
app.get('/',function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('middleware 1');
    req.path = req.url = '/next';
    next();
});

app.use('/next',function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('middleware2');
    next()
});

app.use('/next',function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('middleware3');
    next();
});
```

It will print.

```
middleware1
middleware2
middleware3
```

Comment: Can you explain why it print middleware2, middleware3, middleware1 ? Thank you!

Comment: It won't prints `middleware2 middleware3 middleware1`. It will just print one of the three according of the requested url.

Comment: @PhạmNgọcChuyển, There was some mistake in the previous code but now I have edited it, please check it.

Comment: That is not working in case I have to rewrite image path.

Answer (score 0):

You should not rewrite all the url. The `req.url` inherit from Node's HTTP module ([check here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_url)) which represent the relative path.

Based on your code, a solution could be :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  req.url = req.originalUrl + 'nxt';
  console.log('middleware1');
  next();
});

app.use('/nxt', function (req, res, next) {
 console.log('middleware2');
 next();
});

app.use('/nxt', function (req, res, next) {
 console.log('middleware3');
 next();
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Note that because they have the same path, you could chain it this way :

```
app.use('/nxt',function (req, res, next) {
 console.log('middleware2');
 next();
}, function (req, res, next) {
 console.log('middleware3');
 next();
});
```

Note also that it is not usually what happens. I think it should send a redirection response to the client (`res.redirect(req.originalUrl + 'nxt')`) which will make a new request to `/nxt`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But why I replace `app.use('/nxt'` by `app.get('/nxt'` in middleware2 and middleware3, all middleware were executed for http://localhost:3000 ??

Comment: @PhạmNgọcChuyển Because of this line : `req.url = req.originalUrl + 'nxt';` which "re-route" your request from `/` to `/nxt`, if you remove this line, even with the three as `app.get` it will only triggered the first one.